# Isometry in a finite dimensional vector space is always surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

My book defines an isometry as a linear operator between two vector spaces X and Y where:

$$\|T(x)\|=\|x\|$$

Later it has a sentence which I do not understand.

> If we have a finite dimensional normed vector space where $T$ is an isometry of $X$ into $X$, then $T$ is also onto.

How do we know that it is also onto?

Comment: An isometry is always injective. An injective linear map from a finite-dimensional vector space to itself is also surjective.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, is this difficult to show?, that is show that: "An injective linear map from a finite-dimensional vector space to itself is also surjective"

Comment: It's among the most basic facts in Linear Algebra. To show that, look at the dimension of the image.

Comment: It's immediate from the rank formula. $$\dim V = \dim \ker T + \dim \operatorname{im} T.$$

Comment: See [the rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much! I see that this answers my question. I am also wondering if there is a shortcut to showing this, or do we have to "go through" all the things that leads to that therem. I tried it like this but I am stuck: let z be an element of X, I must show that there is a k such that T(k)=z,etcetc., or do I absolutely need to go back to the linear algebra theorem?, thanks for the help!

Comment: I improved the formatting a bit. Please proofread more carefully in the future. A better way to type norm symbol is `\|x\|`.

Answer (score 3):

A direct proof, in response to your comment:

Let $T$ be an isometry, and let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a basis of $X$.  We note that the vectors $T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)$ must be linearly independent.

Why?  Suppose otherwise.  That is, suppose that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i T(v_i) = 0
$$
for some choice of $a_1,\dots,a_n$ not all zero.  It follows that
$$
T\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i\right) = 0
$$
So, we have $\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i\right\| \neq 0$ but $\|T\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i\right)\| = 0$, which is a contradiction.  (It is also possible to get a contradiction from the injectivity of $T$).

So, $T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)$ is a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $X$, which means that these vectors form a basis of $X$.

So, let $v \in X$ be arbitrarily chosen.  There exist $a_i$ so that $v = \sum_{i=1}^n a_iT(v_i)$.  It follows that $v = T(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i)$.

So, $T$ is indeed onto.